# Animate text to the top-right corner of the screen

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a question with 4 options on the webpage.The score board is on the top-right corner of the screen

```
<div id="score" style="position:fixed;top:0;right:0;">
<p><b>Score:</b>1234</p>
</div>
```

Now when the user hits the correct answer in the first attempt I want to fade-in the text `+10` on the center of the screen which then floats to the top-right corner where score is increased by 10.

I am done with the logical part which is updating the score,but the CSS part is creating headache for me.For fade-in the text "+10" (maybe I can use z-index to make it appear out of the screen) and animate it to top-right corner, I need slight help with either a snippet or a tutorial.

I have intermediate experience in CSS and couldn't figure out the trick for the required animation.I tried on google but having problem with the keywords.Please help

Comment: See jQuery `.css` method : http://api.jquery.com/css/. Do you need the `fadeIn` or  to move the `div` ?

Comment: Perhaps a jsfiddle would be helpful?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed:First `+10` fades in and that same thing moves to the top-right corner

Comment: 'fade-in +10' - explain. Did you implement it ? How ?

Comment: @IstiaqueAhmed:"+10" is the text that fades in,meaning that you have earned 10 points, the the same text floats to the top-right scoreboard meaning that "+10" has been added to your account score.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You basically do four steps:

- Create the "+10" text absolutely positioned wherever you want it. Initially hidden.
- Fade the text in - `.fadeIn()`
- Move the text to the corner - `.animate()`
- Fade the text out - `.fadeOut()`

See the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/_abl/kz6WY/

Comment: :Exactly what I wanted